# Describing convex hulls in purely metrical terms

Tags: convex-analysis, euclidean-geometry, convex-optimization

Let $X$ denote a Euclidean space; take $X = \mathbb{R}^n$ for concreteness. Now consider $x,y \in X$. Then the line segment joining $x$ and $y,$ hereafter denoted $[x,y]$, can be described in algebraic terms as the set of all possible convex combinations of $x$ and $y$. That is, $[x,y]$ is the convex hull of $\{x,y\}$. This line segment can also be described in geometric terms as the set of all points that minimizes the sum of distances to $x$ and $y$. Symbolically:

$$[x,y] = \mathop{\mathrm{arg}\,\mathrm{min}}_{p:X}\left( d(p,x)+d(p,y)\right)$$

Now suppose we have $3$ points, $x,y$ and $z$. Then their convex hull is a (filled-in) triangle. I'd like to describe this triangle as the set of all points minimizing something. The expression

$$(*) \qquad \mathop{\mathrm{arg}\,\mathrm{min}}_{p:X}\left( d(p,x)+d(p,y)+d(p,z)\right)$$

doesn't do the trick, since this is just the [Fermat point](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fermat_point) of the triangle under question. Sum of squares doesn't work, either.

> **Question.** Does there exist a function $f : \mathbb{R}_{\geq 0}^3 \rightarrow \mathbb{R}_{\geq 0}$ such that for all Euclidean spaces
>   $X$ and all $x,y,z \in X$, the convex hull of $\{x,y,z\}$ equals the following? $$\qquad \mathop{\mathrm{arg}\,\mathrm{min}}_{p:X}f(d(p,x),d(p,y),d(p,z))$$

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That would be really cool. But there is no such function, even for triples of points in $\mathbb{R}^1$.

Indeed, take a triple $(a,b,c)$ of positive numbers. Let $x=-a$, $y=b$, $z=c$. The point $t=0$ is an interior point of the convex hull, and has distances $a,b,c$ to the points $x,y,z$. Consider moving $t$ slightly to the left or to the right of $0$: it stays  within the convex hull, so the function $f$ does not change. Conclusion:

- $f$ is constant on lines with the direction vector $\langle 1,1,-1\rangle$, as well as (by symmetry)  $\langle 1,-1,1\rangle$ and $\langle -1,1,1\rangle$.

This implies that $f$ is identically constant, because one can go from $(a,b,c)$ to any other point $(a',b',c')$ moving along such lines. Indeed, the combination
$$
(a,b,c)+\epsilon(1,1,-1)+\epsilon(1,-1,1) = (a+2\epsilon,b,c)
$$
enables one to move along the first coordinate axis, and similarly for others.

---

If the collinear triples are excluded, the situation doesn't change. One can slightly perturb the triple $x=-a$, $y=b$, $z=c$ to make it non-collinear; moving $t$ along a line as before, conclude that $f$ is constant on certain almost-linear curves. Put together short pieces of such curves to move around in the $3$-space.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I'll need some time to think about this.

Answer (score 2):

An analogous formula for triangles is
$$ \operatorname{conv}\ \{x,y,z\} = \mathop{\operatorname{arg min}}_p\ (A(x,y,p) + A(x,p,z) + A(p,y,z))  $$
where $A(a,b,c)$ denotes the area of the triangle with vertices $a,b,c$.

Not quite what you wanted, but there it is.  If you really want distances only, perhaps you could compute the areas by Heron's formula.

---

A proof, you say?  Well... no, I haven't worked out a proof in detail.  Let me sketch some ideas that could probably be turned into a proof or two with some effort.

First, that formula doesn't work when $x,y,z$ are collinear; let's just assume they're not.

Other than that, it's the same idea as in the one-dimensional case: if $p$ is outside the triangle then the triangles whose areas we compute overlap, so we double-count, but if $p$ is inside then we get exactly $A(x,y,z)$.  To do it formally, I think the major ingredients would be (1) reduction to the case where $p$ is in the affine hull of $x,y,z$ (if it's not, its projection $p'$ onto that plane makes lesser areas), and (2) Radon's theorem and some analysis of cases (to verify that we do get double counting whenever $p$ is outside).

Alternatively... I bet there's some slick way where we embed the plane in $\mathbb R^3$ as the plane $x_3=1$, take the triangles to correspond to tetrahedra (with fourth vertex at the origin), relate the areas of those triangles to the volumes of those tetrahedra, and write out everything in $3\times 3$ determinants.  Then, I bet, you'll find that there's an expression like $A(x,y,p)+A(x,p,z)+A(p,y,z)$ except with alternating signs, computing the volume of the convex hull of the origin and the four points in the plane, using determinants as *signed* areas.  Obviously the volume of that solid is minimized when $p$ is inside $xyz$, and since we take absolute values, we get an even larger number...  Well, like I said, I haven't worked out the details, but I bet this would work.

Comment: Nice! Can you prove this works? But anyway, this is really cool. It means that if we have a set $X$ equipped with a function $A : X^3 \rightarrow \mathbb{R}_{\geq 0}$, we can find out, given $x,y,z \in X$, what set of points we're actually measuring the area *of*. It remains to find appropriate conditions on $A$, of course. Something resembling the metric space axioms, methinks.

Comment: Another idea would be to start with a metric space $(X,d)$ and use [Heron's formula](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Heron%27s_formula) to define an area function $A : X^3 \rightarrow \mathbb{R}_{\geq 0}$.